# proguard is removing Interface with one implementor

Tags: android, proguard

I wrote a simple android application,
I created an interface (MyHttpClient) extending apache's HttpClient Interface and created one implementing class called MyHttpClientImpl.
While building my project, I used proguard to obfuscate my apk, and I noticed that in the optimization process, the interface MyHttpClient is removed from the apk.
How can the application work (it is still working) without the physical class MyHttpClient?
How does it knows that MyHttpClientImpl is extending/implementing apache's HttpClient (where if at all does this connection stored)?
Thanks.

Comment: Most likely ProGuard is renaming your class to something cryptic like `a`.

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard's optimization step may merge an interface with its sole implementing class. The resulting class should still implement all its other interfaces, in this case HttpClient. You can check this by looking at the resulting class with javap:

```
javap -classpath processed.jar mypackage.MyHttpClient
```

Comment: Would an `instanceof` statement fail?

Answer (score 0):

Because Interfaces in java are not checked at execution time, only compile time. The exception is when you use reflection, then you don't want to remove the interface.

Comment: The apache lib allows me send a request.
If I wish to use this lib, I need to implement HttpClient.
If there is no link between MyHttpClientImpl and HttpClient (the only connection was in the removed interface), how does the it knows that I'm using the apache lib?

Comment: Again, because It's just an interface and java does not check that at runtime, only at compiletime.